# ios:Where do i save the thumbnails generated by alassets library

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I want to create a video browser using ALAssetsLibrary. i have a step forward in How to use AssetsLibrary. but the problem is in creating thumbnails. i mean where to store the thumbnails if i have >300 videos. now i am saving them in an array which is causing to crash.where do i save the thumbnails for temporarily.

and please let me know what are the things i have to look at.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking at NSTemporaryDirectory() on this page https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html.
You can create files for each of the thumbnails in temp directory and just maintain an array of file names/locations in your program.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without saving them into files

Comment: This is what I did when I wanted to store some video data. I could not find any other better way then.